# Как обновить виджет в окне приложения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Мой код наполняет контейнер `box` виджетами `QLabel`, между которых помещает `self.art` - изображение с закругленными краями, которое он получает с помощью класса `Label`. В конец контейнера попадает кнопка `btn`, которая должна менять картинку в `self.art`, но я не знаю, как это сделать. Конечно, можно было бы переложить все элементы контейнера снова или использовать `QGridLayout`, но, может быть, есть другой способ обновить виджет `self.art`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(150, 150)
        self.setMinimumSize(150, 150)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(150, 150, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 1')
        box.addWidget(label1)
        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 2')
        box.addWidget(label2)

        self.art = Label('picture1') # Изначальное изображение, которое нужно заменить
        box.addWidget(self.art)

        label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 3')
        box.addWidget(label3)
        label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 4')
        box.addWidget(label4)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.remake)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def remake(self):
        self.art = Label('picture2') # Изображение, на которое нужно заменить текущее изображение


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы отделил код установки картинки в `Label` от его конструктора в отдельный метод (например **setPicture**), тогда не нужно будет пересоздавать `Label`, чтобы поменять картинку.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(150, 150)
        self.setMinimumSize(150, 150)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            150, 150, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 1')
        box.addWidget(label1)
        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 2')
        box.addWidget(label2)

        self.art = Label('picture1') # Изначальное изображение, которое нужно заменить
        box.addWidget(self.art)

        label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 3')
        box.addWidget(label3)
        label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 4')
        box.addWidget(label4)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked = self.remake)
        box.addWidget(btn)

    def remake(self):
        self.art.setPicture('picture2') # Изображение, на которое нужно заменить текущее изображение


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Почему-то выдает ошибку `QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted`

Comment: @MAXIM045, к сожалению, не могу сейчас проверить. Обновил ответ, добавил закрытие painter'а и удаление ссылки на `target`

Comment: Все работает, спасибо:)